# What does the transition matrix for this diagram look like?

Tags: matrices, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

[image]

The problem states that:

[image]

I did it the wrong way, but I fully understand their method. I tried to do it by finding that $P(X_1 =1)$ or $P(X_2 = 0)$ or $P(X_2=1)$ and so on, it got me to: $P(X_2=0) = P(Y_1=0, Y_2=0)$ or that $P(X_2=1)=P(Y_1=0,Y_2=1)+P(Y_1=1,Y_2=0)$ and so on.

What is wrong with solving it like that?

Also does it work? Because, I find that the equation needs to have some independence which is what I assumed i.e.
\begin{align}
P(X_2 = 1) &= P(Y_1=0,Y_2=1) + P(Y_1=1,Y_2=0) = \\
           &= P(Y_1 = 0)*P(Y_2=1) + P(Y_1=1)*P(Y_2=0).
\end{align}

Also, because $X_0 = 0$.

Generally, can anyone solve for me $P(X_t=0)$ or $P(X_t=1)$, and show me how; if there is a condition of independence that allows it to be solved my way can you explain why? And also show me what form I should put the transition matrix of this diagram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Markov process, as you can easily prove that for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$
$$
P(X_{n+1}=x_{n+1}|X_n=x_n,X_{n-1}=x_{n-1},\ldots,X_0=x_0)=P(X_{n+1}=x_{n+1}|X_n=x_n)
$$
In other words, the probability at the time $n+1$ to pass from a state to another depends only on the state at time $n$ and doesn't depend on the previous states. In this case at the time $n$ we have $n+1$ possible configurations $\{0,1,\ldots,n\}$, and similarly at the time $n+1$ we have $n+2$ possible configurations $\{0,1,\ldots,n+1\}$. So you can use transition matrices to describe the process:
$$
M_n(i,j)=P(X_{n+1}=j-1|X_{n}=i-1)\qquad i=1,\ldots,n+1\quad j=1,\ldots,n+2
$$
For example
$$
M_0=
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{3}{4} & \frac{1}{4}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
M_1=
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{5}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & 0 \\
0 &\frac{2}{3} & \frac{1}{3}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
M_2=
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{5}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & 0 & 0 \\
0 &\frac{3}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & 0 \\
0 & 0 &\frac{2}{3} & \frac{1}{3}  \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
And so on. Then the vector of the total probability at the time $n$ to be in a specific state is $Q_n=M_0M_1M_2\ldots M_{n-1}$, and it will be a $(n+1)$-dimensional (row) vector s.t.
$$
P(X_{n}=j-1)=Q_n(j)\qquad j\text{-th component of }Q_n
$$
To determinate an explicit expression of $M_n$, for $n\geq1$, we can observe that
$$
P(X_{n+1}=x_n+1|X_n=x_n)=\frac{1}{6}\left(1+\frac{x_n}{n}\right)
$$

$$
P(X_{n+1}=x_n|X_n=x_n)=1-\frac{1}{6}\left(1+\frac{x_n}{n}\right)=\frac{1}{6}\left(5-\frac{x_n}{n}\right)
$$

So we have that $M_n$ is a $(n+1)\times(n+2)$ matrix where
$$
M_n(i,j)=P(X_{n+1}=j-1|X_{n}=i-1)=\left\lbrace
\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{1}{6}\left(5-\frac{i-1}{n}\right) & \text{if }\; j=i\\
\frac{1}{6}\left(1+\frac{i-1}{n}\right) & \text{if }\; j=i+1\\
0 & \text{elsewhere}
\end{array}\right.
$$
If we want to represent $Q_n$ recursively we can write
\begin{align*}
Q_n(j)&=Q_{n-1}M_{n-1}^j\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}Q_{n-1}(k)M_{n-1}(k,j)\\
&=Q_{n-1}(j)M_{n-1}(j,j)+Q_{n-1}(j-1)M_{n-1}(j-1,j)\\
&=\frac{1}{6}\left(5-\frac{j-1}{n-1}\right)Q_{n-1}(j)+\frac{1}{6}\left(1+\frac{j-2}{n-1}\right)Q_{n-1}(j-1)
\end{align*}
(if $j<2$ in the last two equations the second term of the sum is zero).

Answer (score 1):

Let $i,j\geq0$. For any $n\geq0$ you have that
$$
P(X_{n+1}=j\mid X_{n}=i)=\begin{cases}
P(Y_{n+1}=0\mid X_{n}=i)&\text{if }j=i, \\
P(Y_{n+1}=1\mid X_{n}=i)&\text{if }j=i+1, \\
0&\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$
We know that these probabilities can be written as
$$
P(Y_{n+1}=1\mid X_{n}=i)=\begin{cases}
\tfrac{1}{4}&\text{if }n=0, \\
\tfrac{1}{6}\left(1+\tfrac{i}{n}\right)&\text{if }n>0,
\end{cases}
$$
and $P(Y_{n+1}=0\mid X_{n}=i)=1-P(Y_{n+1}=1\mid X_{n}=i)$.

This lets you calculate the transition probabilities directly. You can see that the transition probabilities and the number of possible states change with $n$. For each $n$ you could write down a transition matrix $P(n)$ which describes the transition probabilities going from time $n$ to $n+1$. Thats is,
$$
P_{ij}(n)=P(X_{n+1}=j\mid X_{n}=i),\qquad(0\leq i,j\leq n+1).
$$

Comment: Is this how I should format most solutions for transition probabilities? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes. Transition probabilities are basically just probabilities on the form $P(X_{n+1}=j\mid X_n=i)$ for $i,j$ in the state space.

Comment: What about for some $P(X_n = x_n, X_{n-1} = x_{n-1},....,X = x)$ of arbitrary value n? For specifically that joint distribution; for instance: some states H,S,D and $P(X_3 = 1, X_4 = 0)$ would I have to use all the sample paths available from $X_0$?